# How would one measure the frequencies of different sounds/music?

Tags: acoustics, frequency, home-experiment

I'm doing a science fair project and I'm trying to measure which frequencies are unappealing/appealing to the human brain and how they react to said frequencies. I've looked around for a little bit but have yet to find a solid answer on how this could be recorded, whether it's through a specific device or software. I need to complete this project to get into AP Physics, and help would be much appreciated.

Comment: How wpuld you determine if the frequency is unappealing or appealing? There is no device for this.

Comment: Sounds interesting! I would recommend being more precise on what you want to measure. If you want to measure people's reactions, PSE is probably not the forum to look into. If your goal is to find out what frequencies are in, say, a sound file, then you basically just need to do a fourier transform.

Comment: https://www.audacityteam.org/ is one open source tool for recording, playback, analysis and manipulation of audio

Comment: I don't think that individual frequencies have this effect. It is rather the combinations of frequencies that are pleasant or unplesant. Even though the sound made by chalk screeching on a blackboard may be an example of unpleasant sound. AIt will be interesting to find the spectrum of such a sound.